# How can I call specific function if requested URL is not found?

Tags: php, api, wp-remote-request

My website is fully API based and builds pages/posts from API data.
I was thinking to create something like PHP magic function __call to call specific function when requested URL would return 404, but do it before it happens, so I could send API request and create the page on the fly and return the previously missing page to user.

What are the options to do it? I know wp_insert_post is the way to add new post via PHP, but I can't find how to hook into initial request before 404 is thrown to initiate wp_remote_request.

Basically I think I miss the filter/action name for it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use template_redirect filter to perform check on request you get in wordpress.

```
add_filter('template_redirect', 'my_404_override' );

function my_404_override() {
    global $wp_query;

    if (!$wp_query->post) {         // Check if any post is found. If not its 404.
        status_header( 200 );
        $wp_query->is_404=false;

        // Create post object
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'My post',
          'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_category' => array(8,39)
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );      // Add new post in to the system
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) );   // Finally redirect it to the post.
    }
}
```

This will create a new post for you & also will redirect user to that post. Well, frankly speaking it's a fix to perform the task but it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add this logic *after* WP churns through the query and concludes it's 404, but *before* it output 404 error page then you likely need to be working in range of logic contained in [`template-loader.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.9/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php) file.

Most of it is about determining template file for the conditionals fitting current request. You will likely need both to adjust template file choice and probably adjust main `WP_Query` object and headers.

It seems a little involved to do on the fly. If you don't really *need* persistent post you might better go the way of creating custom rewrite rules and not follow "post" logic altogether.